# Salt state not working in combination with pillardata

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following salt state:

```
freeradius:
  pkg.installed

radiusgroup:
  group.present:
    - name: radiusadm
    - gid: 666

{% for user, args in pillar['users'].items() %}
  {% if ( user not in pillar['absents'] ) and ( 'radiuspassword' in args ) %}
  shadow_hash_{{ user }}:
    user.present:
      - name: {{ user }}
      - password: {{ args['radiuspassword'] }}
  {% endif %}  
{% endfor %}
```

And have the following pillars

```
groups:
  radiusd:
    gid: 95

users:
  user1:
    radiuspassword: 'password1'
  user2:
    radiuspassword: 'password2'

absents:
  a2user1:
  a2user2:
```

I want to make this code work, I get the message:

```
Data failed to compile:
```

---

```
State 'radiusgroup' in SLS 'radiusd' is not formed as a list
```

Please advice me how to go from here, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is in the declaration of `pillar`. Also having indents in state file in `for` and `if` blocks may cause issues. The error states that `radiusgroup` is not formed as a list. So we should form a list with `groups`.

Example pillar:

```yml
groups:
  - name: radiusd
    gid: 95

users:
  - name: user1
    radiuspassword: password1
  - name: user2
    radiuspassword: password2

absents:
  - a2user1
  - a2user2
```

Note that I have used similar structure for the list of users as well. Then we can have state file as:

```yml
{% for group in pillar['groups'] %}
radiusgroup_{{ group.name }}:
  group.present:
    - name: {{ group.name }}
    - gid: {{ group.gid }}
{% endfor %}

{% for user in pillar['users'] %}
{% if (user.radiuspassword is defined) and (user.name not in pillar['absents']) %}
shadow_hash_{{ user.name }}:
  user.present:
    - name: {{ user.name }}
    - password: {{ user.radiuspassword }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

If the `pillar` is in your control, it would be best to define it *exactly* how you want. So that you can avoid using complicated Jinja expressions in a state file.

Comment: Thank you @seshadri_c, your code works and learns me something new. I am altering someone else his code, but I do have control of the pillar data. The only thing you need to change is the line where user.password is mentioned, it should be user.radiuspassword.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing out! I corrected it (typo). Glad it helped.